# Eclipse formatting of assignment via method call

Tags: eclipse, formatter

What I want (when formatting in Eclipse):

```
      Path file = write(FILE_SYSTEM.getPath(fileName), transactionStrings, 
            CHARSET, CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, WRITE);
```

What it is doing:

```
      Path file =
            write(FILE_SYSTEM.getPath(fileName), transactionStrings, CHARSET,
                  CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, WRITE);
```

Line length is 80, tab widths set to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the solution.

- Windows > Preferences > Java Code Style > Formatter > Edit
- Line Wrapping > Expressions > Assignments > Line wrapping policy: Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Set line length in Eclipse formatter (Window->Preferences->Java->Code style->Formatter) to higher value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not what I am after i.e. I am not going to change line lengths to solve a formatting issue.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram and why downvoting? explain please more precise your problem, you can tweak your formatter in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code style -> Formatter as you can, check New Lines section.

Comment: Hi Ladislav. I down-voted because I didn't think the answer was helpful. Truly, there is nothing personal about it. I showed the effect I was after with the first code snippet and in my view it is clear that changing line lengths is not a good way to solve a formatting issue of this nature.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram use `@` to notify commenter (see help after text area) and read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) please